# Internal Server error while calling an Java method from JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts, struts-config

This is my JSP

`extra.jsp`:

```jsp
<%@taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean"%>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1><bean:write name="HelloWorldForm" property="message">
</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

this formBean

`HelloWorldForm.java`:

```
package com.redhat.rhn.frontend.action.common;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
public class HelloWorldForm extends ActionForm{
    String message="HelloWorld!";
    public String getMessage() {
            return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
    }
}
```

this is action

`HelloWorldAction.java`:

```
package com.redhat.rhn.frontend.action;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

import com.redhat.rhn.frontend.action.common.HelloWorldForm;

public class HelloWorldAction extends Action{
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
    throws Exception {
            HelloWorldForm HelloWorldForm = (HelloWorldForm) form;
            HelloWorldForm.setMessage("Hello World! Struts");      
            return mapping.findForward("success");
    }
}
```

I have added following code in struts-config file

`struts-config.xml`:

```xml
<form-bean name="HelloWorldForm"
        type="com.redhat.rhn.frontend.common.HelloWorldForm">
</form-bean>


<action path="/extra"
scope="request"
name="HelloWorldForm"
type="com.redhat.rhn.frontend.action.HelloWorldAction">
<forward name="success" path="/WEB-INF/pages/extra.jsp" />
</action>
```

I get internal server error when I try to access the extra.jsp from browser
The intention behind printing hello world is to get to know how to call java method from jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code 500 is produced via jasper compiler when compiling JSP page that has errors

The tag

```jsp
<bean:write name="HelloWorldForm" property="message">
```

isn't closed and compiler will result the error with 500 status code